# How to limit a query to certain dates

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I have what I hope is a very simple issue, but I can't work it out.

In management studio, a date value appears as:

2015-07-20 14:50:20.000

I'm ok about formatting that to appear as 20 July 2015 but, when I put in my WHERE query,

Date >=2015-07-20

All date values are coming through, starting from 2009! Is there any way I can add a statement to just bring through dates from a particular period, e.g. today's date or between last week and this week?

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose your date in quotes. Like:

```
Date >= '2015-07-20'
```

Otherwise you're asking it to compare the value with `2015 - 7 - 20` -- e.g. 1988 which when implicitly converted to a `datetime` object in your `WHERE` becomes `1905-06-12 00:00:00.000` (the start of the time stamp range (1900-01-01) plus the number of days).

Answer (score 0):

You can Create a parameter for Date then in your query have it say where date >= @date or have a @BeginDate and @EndDate parameters and say where Date between @BeginDate and @EndDate.